# Какие есть системы полнотекстового поиска?

Tags: база-данных, сервер, поиск, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть сервер на 4 ТБ, содержащий различные файлы. Необходимо организовать полнотекстовый поиск по файлам. Например, нужно получить все файлы, которые содержат определенный кусок текста (не слово, а именно текст). Как это лучше всего организовать?

Слышал про Azure Search, но там все как-то сложно и дорого. Есть ли иные подобные системы?

Comment: На чем сервер, какая ОС/БД ?

Comment: интересуют системы поиска для различных вариантов ОС/БД